# Is this component file format for react native good?

Tags: react.js, react-native

I'm new to React Native.
I wonder if the following project file structure is ok to use for the rest of my project.

Here is an example of component:

```
import React, {useMemo} from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native'
import {Text} from 'react-native-paper'

// Import the hook that give me my theme variables
import {useAppTheme} from '../Main'

// Import the type structure of my theme variables
import {ThemeType} from './themes'

function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  // Hook from react-native-paper lib, to access my theme variables
  const theme = useAppTheme()

  // I keep my StyleSheet at the end of the file, 
  // and call a function here to make "theme" var available
  // to my StyleSheet through the getStyles function.
  // I used "useMemo" so it doesn't reevaluated on every render
  const styles = useMemo(() => getStyles(theme), [theme])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const getStyles = (theme: ThemeType) =>
  StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.background,
    },
  })

export default App
```

I still think that this may be too much boilerplate for a component file, but I can't think of a better way to structure it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.